# Java Scheduled tasks (in windows)

Tags: java, windows, parsing, service, scheduling

Im facing a problem where i want to schedule a certain java application to run every x days, or every x minutes. I really want to have a platform independant solution, but i've given up on hope to find a nice solution.

To achieve the scheduling, i've been through several solutions, one being services and one being to use the windows api.
I really dont like to use a service, it doesnt deploy well in my project. I would have to use some scripts to install the service, wich just doesnt seems to be the right solution for me.

I've also been through windows's scheduling services. They seem perfect for the job. But i'm having trouble parsing the command line. I want to be able to modify my task after i installed it. but when i query the command line tool, the output language may vary (locale).

Maybe there is a solution that implements different stategies per operating system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, try [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).  No scripts, no services, just a JAR in your app.  All Java - works on any OS.

I don't see why platform-independence is required.  My experience is that scheduled jobs rarely move off the server where they're deployed, unless either the need for the job goes away or the server is retired.  They *just don't move*.

If Quartz isn't your cup of tea, I'd recommend finding a server admin who knows Windows better than you do to deploy your cron job and be done with it.

Comment: I've seen their website, and i think this is not quite the solution im looking for. This means i have to have a jvm running all the time, wich is no option for me..

Comment: Platform-independent was your stated requirement.  Why is having the JVM running all the time not an option?  Maybe you just need to find someone that understands Windows cron jobs better than you do.  Scheduled jobs just don't migrate from server to server that often.  Why is platfom independence so important?

Comment: because the application runs on multiple operating systems. I can write different implementations for different operating systems though.
I understand the windows scheduled task api enough to schedule a task using the command line.. i can even make a wrapper for it in java, but the problem is that the command line tool has different output languages ;)

Comment: also, the vm might get shut down. because it is in the procces list, the user might kill the wrong java.exe procces.

Answer (score 2):

Although for me "platform independent solution" and "i want to use Windows Scheduling service" are sort of contradictory (and I agree with duffymo that Quartz is probably the best pure Java solution), some Powershell scripting might make manipulating scheduled programs in Windows a bit easier - look [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/07/28/powershell-script-to-retrieve-scheduled-tasks-on-a-remote-machine-task-scheduler-api.aspx) and [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/08/06/powershell-script-to-schedule-a-task-task-scheduler-api.aspx) and [here](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/40/view.asp?id=10116) plus hunderds of other places that discuss Powershell.  And modern Windows should all have Powershell on board.

Comment: I agree with you that using the windows scheduling api is not platform independant ;).
as i've stated in the first paragraph: 
"but i've given up on hope to find a nice solution :P"